# Pass a variable to require.context?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am requiring all files from a directory with webpack `require.context` like so:

```
export default class Svg {
    constructor() {
        const icons = require.context('example/images', true, /\.svg$/);
    }
}
```

This work fine but I would like to pass a path to my constructor and set the `require.context` path with either the constructor value if given or a default if it is not given.

Using a variable like this results in an error though:

```
const icons = require.context(path, true, /\.svg$/);
```

> WARNING in ./src/Svg.js
>   11:20-27 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in
>   which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Is there a way to get around this or am I simply abusing the require.context functionality here?

Comment: This should be working fine. You've said, "Using a variable like this results in an error though" and the message posted says "WARNING", in all caps even. Am I missing something or are you interpreting this warning message as an error?

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately you can't, because it must be statically analyzable.

Read [webpack issue #4772](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772).

This may change in the future release, now Webpack is on version 4.